# []byte manipulation with substring matching

Tags: arrays, go

I am new to Golang and want to achieve the following. Are there any go utilities to do this please ?

[linux]# lspci | grep "Ethernet Contro"

`01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)

01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)`

I have the above output of "lcpci" as []byte.. Now I want to be able to extract "01:00.0" as a string , assuming I find "Ethernet Controller" .. How do I achieve this with regex/string/byte utilities in GO ? I tried to browse through, but not able to conclude..

Comment: If you've already separated `"Ethernet Controller"`, what problem did you have getting the previous field?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Index

Comment: Actually I was thinking of using bytes.Contains to find the Ethernet Controller string.. But this only returns TRUE/FALSE.. Once I do that, how do I get the previous values , say "01:00.0" ? Please help

Comment: `b[0:8]`, [`bytes.Split`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes/#Split), [`bytes.Fields`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes/#Fields), all equivalent functions in the [`strings`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings) package. There's lots of ways to break up the data, all well documented, and it all depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will use them

Answer (score 0):

You can split the bytes data using the new line separator, than iterate the slice and verify if your text is present, as following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var data = []byte(`
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
d8:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)
ab:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T (rev 01)`)
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`^(((\d+)|(\w+)):\d+.\d+)`)
    for _, row := range bytes.Split(data, []byte("\n")) {
        if bytes.Contains(row, []byte("Ethernet Controller")) {
            submatch := r.FindString(string(row))
            fmt.Println(submatch)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
01:00.0
01:00.1
01:00.0
d8:00.0
ab:00.0
```

Regexp explanation:

```
^(((\d)|(\w)):\d.\d)

^ asserts position at start of a line
1st Capturing Group (((\d)|(\w)):\d.\d)
2nd Capturing Group ((\d)|(\w))
1st Alternative (\d)
3rd Capturing Group (\d)
\d
matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
2nd Alternative (\w)
4th Capturing Group (\w)
\w
matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\d
matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
\d
matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
The parenthesis delimit the group to extract
```

Comment: Thanks much ! This code just worked for me .. If I want to be able to include aphabets also, how do I modify this ? Like I can have 01:00.0 or d8:00.0 or ab:00.0

Comment: Modified as necessary